# How to enable a disabled display device in Windows 10 when real content is not visible on the screen?

Tags: windows-10, display

In my old Windows 10 laptop, I disabled my display device. I have only one display adapter which is a Microsoft Basic Display Adapter.

After a reboot I don't have access to the Windows login page any more. I know it is there but I can't see it because the screen remains in the previous stage showing the windows 10 flag and the rotating wheel.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> doesn't show me anything, but when I touch Power button the laptop shuts down without needing to hold it down for 5 sec.

I am not able to interact through the screen, because the only thing visible is the Windows flag and the rotating wheel.

Is there any way to enable my display device again?

Comment: If you disconnect the device physical the windows will return to your single display.  You can then reconnect the display and enable it within the window that was moved

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for your response, but it is a laptop, and there is only one display. Would you please explain by more details what you mean to "disconnect the device physical(y)"?

Comment: You didn't make it clear which display was disabled.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you. I edited my question.

Comment: If Windows fails to boot 3 times in a row, you will be presented with the ability to boot into Safe Mode with Adanced Startup.

Comment: @Ramhound You are right. But something funny happens: It enters automatic repair mode, and successfully repairs windows, and doesn't show the Advanced Startup options!! :) Then it restarts itself, and surprisingly again goes to the previous state that I said before :(